# Which is newer firmware, and how could I update mine?

Tags: ssd, firmware, nvme

I have an NVMe SSD: SAMSUNG MZ9LQ1T0HBLB-00B00.

My firmware on it is: "FXM7601Q".

However I have seen people in forums with the same SSD with firmware of "FXM7AK1Q".

I tried to update the firmware with

```
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

But it didn't find any updates for this SSD.

I really wish to know if my version is the latest, and if not, how can I update it from Debian's command line (no GUI).

I tried my best to look for this version information online, but Google was not my friend with this one.

Running `sudo fwupdmgr get-devices`:

```
└─SAMSUNG MZ9LQ1T0HBLB-00B00:
      Device ID:          ---
      Summary:            NVM Express Solid State Drive
      Current version:    FXM7601Q
      Vendor:             Samsung Electronics Co Ltd (NVME:0x144D)
      Serial Number:      ---
      GUIDs:              --- ← STORAGE-DELL-109819
                          ---
      Device Flags:       • Updatable
                          • System requires external power source
                          • Needs a reboot after installation
```

Running `sudo fwupdmgr update`:

```
Devices with no available firmware updates:
 • ---
 • SAMSUNG MZ9LQ1T0HBLB-00B00
No updatable devices
```

Comment: I'm experiencing huge temperatures during write (100 °C).

Comment: Cool.  Gotcha.  Is there something in the update that implies that it deals with this?  I would step carefully.

Comment: See if the computer manufacturer supplies SSD firmware updates. Mine does.

Comment: After looking, yes agreed.. this looks like a beneficial update.. I am seeing what I can do.

Comment: what does `sudo fwupdmgr get-devices` show you?  Also.. is it possible that there is already a problem by exceeding the max temp?

Comment: Samsung does not really appear to upload firmware to LVFS. You cannot rely on `fwupdmgr`.

Comment: I mentioned using the computer manufacturer's update app to check for SSD firmware. I just got an SSD firmware update today (Lenovo APP) on my Samsung SSD.  Update succeeded and restarted the computer. All well.

Comment: @John: it's installed to a custom Debian-based linux PC.

Comment: I have updated SSD firmware before and I do not know any other way than vendor software to do the update